# How can I make Visual Studio XAML code editor not lose focus when switching among documents?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, cursor, focus, designer

I'm editing in Visual Studio 2013 two XAML files.

I'm doing it using "Vertical Split" mode doing edits in one part - XAML code editor and tracking changes with my eyes in second part - visual designer.

When I switch between these documents using Ctrl+Tab keys, my cursor is gone from code editor so I must use mouse to bring it back. How can I enforce the IDE to not touch my cursor?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can assign this by going to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and searching for SplitPane. You should be able to assign shortcut keys for the following values:

Window.NextSplitPane
Window.PreviousSplitPane

NextSplitPane will cycle among the splits